# Decision tree classification code for categorical data

Tags: decision-trees

[image]

how can I apply decision tree classification to get malnutrition status(target variables are wasting, stunting,overweight,underweight)

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
You need to convert your target column into numbers first. You can try the following:

```
df['status'] = df['status'].map({'wasting': 0, 'stunting': 1, 'overweight': 2, 'underweight': 3})
```

After this you can run your Decision tree and you will get the df['status'] in number format. And then you can convert it back to strings using the following:

```
reverse_mapping = {0: 'wasting', 1: 'stunting', 2: 'overweight', 3: 'underweight'}
df['status'] = df['status'].map(reverse_mapping)
```